# Find $E[(X − c)^+]$ when $X$ is normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, statistics

Find $E[(X − c)^+]$ when $X$ is normal with
mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. where

$$
y^+ = 
\begin{cases} 
  y  & \text{if y>0} \\
 0  & \text{if y<0}
\end{cases}
$$

there is no way I can integrate $\int^{\infty}_c(x-c)f(x) dx$ so is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate it, it's just that the result is not expressible in elementary functions.  You can express it using the error function, or using the standard normal CDF.

Comment: okay so how would i express : $\int^{\infty}_cxf(x) dx$? I can figure out the other part but how would I express this part?

Comment: First express it in terms of the standard normal distribution ($\mu = 0$, $\sigma = 1$).  For $\int z e^{-z^2/2}\; dz$ use the change of variables $u = z^2/2$.

Comment: okay I found it for the standard normal (that was actually question a) but how does that help me find it for $X$?

Comment: @Alex simple change of variable